# cannot set optional property to null

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a model class, where I defined an optional property like this:

```js
export class Workflow {
  constructor(
    public id: number,
    public started: Date,
    public documentId: number,
    public document: Document,
    public status: WorkflowStatus,
    public workflowEvents: WorkflowEvent[],
    public startingUserId: number,
    public statusValue?: string,
  ) {}
}
```

I have a pipe too, which transforms the status propery to a string:

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { WorkflowStatus } from '../models/workflowstatus.enum';

@Pipe({ name: "status" })
export class WorkflowStatusPipe implements PipeTransform {
  public transform(value: WorkflowStatus): string {
    switch (value) {
      case WorkflowStatus.ForwardedToApprover: return "TOV";
      case WorkflowStatus.ReadedByApprover: return "OLV";
      case WorkflowStatus.Commented: return "MEGJ";
      case WorkflowStatus.Approved: return "JÓV";
      case WorkflowStatus.ForwardedToManager: return "MAN";
    }
  }
}
```

Then I have document objects. To each document we can have a workflow. I get the documents via api:

```js
    this.documentRepo.getDocuments().subscribe(documents => {
      documents.forEach(function (document) {
        document.workflow.statusValue = new WorkflowStatusPipe().transform(document.workflow?.status);
      });
      this.documents = documents;
    });
```

As you see, I'm trying to transform the status value to a string, if there is a workflow. But I get in the console this error: 'Cannot set property 'statusValue' of null'.

I don't really unterstand, why, because I set the `statusValue` property to an optional property.

How should I modify the code?

EDIT:

this is a document object from the result of getDocuments:

[image]

Another weird thing: if I just simply assign a nonsense string to the statusValue like this, I get the same error:

```js
    this.documentRepo.getDocuments().subscribe(documents => {
      documents.forEach(function (document) {
        document.workflow.statusValue = "x";//new WorkflowStatusPipe().transform(document.workflow?.status);
      });
      this.documents = documents;
    });
```

Comment: Can you share what `Document` is? Also the result of `getDocuments` would be helpful.

Comment: Error message `Cannot set property 'statusValue' of null` means parent of `statusValue` is null. in this case `workflow` property.

Try logging it before you assign.

Comment: Yes, I know this, because to each document CAN belong a workflow. For this, I checked the workflow property with ? for null. If null, then statusValue is null, but it should be ok, because the statusValue property is optional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to handle the case where property `document.workflow` does not exist or is null. Set a default workflow value to documents with no workflow or simply skip the processing in documents with no workflow, something like

```
this.documentRepo.getDocuments().subscribe(documents => {
  documents.forEach(function (document) {
    if (document.workflow) {
      document.workflow['statusValue'] = new WorkflowStatusPipe().transform(document.workflow?.status);
    }
  });
  this.documents = documents;
});
```

Notice also if `document.workflow.status` is not of the values considered in your switch statement you will get undefined as result. Depending on what you expect there you may want to add a default case to return a different value.